# Flutter: State was called without a registered event handler Make sure to register a handler via on<State>((event, emit) {...})

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:testproject_flutter/Service/bloc/bloc.dart';

import '../repository/service_repository.dart';


class ServiceBloc extends Bloc<ServiceEvent, ServiceState> {
  final ServiceRepository serviceRepository;

  ServiceBloc({required this.serviceRepository})
      : super(ServiceLoading());

  Stream<ServiceState> mapEventToState(ServiceEvent event) async* {
    if (event is ServiceLoad) {
      const Text("Service load method");
      yield ServiceLoading();

      try {
        final services = await serviceRepository.getServices();
        Text("This is the service $services");
        yield ServicesLoadSuccess(services);
      } catch (_) {
        yield ServiceOperationFailure();
      }
    }

    if (event is ServiceCreate) {
      try {
        await serviceRepository.createService(event.service);
        final services = await serviceRepository.getServices();
        yield ServicesLoadSuccess(services);
      } catch (_) {
        yield ServiceOperationFailure();
      }
    }

    if (event is ServiceUpdate) {
      try {
        await serviceRepository.updateService(event.service);
        final services = await serviceRepository.getServices();
        yield ServicesLoadSuccess(services);
      } catch (_) {
        yield ServiceOperationFailure();
      }
    }

    if (event is ServiceDelete) {
      try {
        await serviceRepository.deleteService(event.service.id);
        final services = await serviceRepository.getServices();
        yield ServicesLoadSuccess(services);
      } catch (e) {
        Text("Error de,ete=$e");
        yield ServiceOperationFailure();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

above is the code i copied which is MapEventtoState has been depreceated, below is the code where the runtime error happened :

```
BlocProvider.of<ServiceBloc>(context).add(event);
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          ServiceMainScreen.routeName, (route) => false);
```

i have this kind of prob, i want integrate Flutter with .Net core web API. I'm new to flutter so, i just followed the tutorial,i`m encounter an runtime error, where in tutorial use depreceated MapEventtoState method emit event. how to solve this

Comment: have you tried to follow your last post comment ?